# JunitTest DataStream of type Either with flink spector

Tags: junit, apache-flink, flink-cep

I'm creating a test to see if the timeout of my flink pattern functions correctly. I'm using flink spector for this and I have the following testcase:

```java
@Test
public void SameDoor_TwoStatuses_OneSecondTimeoutPattern() {
    // Arrange
    long now = new Date().getTime();
    DoorEvent event1 = new DoorEvent();
    event1.setId(123);
    event1.getDoor().setId(1);
    event1.getDoor().setStatus("statusaaaaaa");
    event1.setTimestamp(now);

    EventTimeInputBuilder<DoorEvent> builder = EventTimeInputBuilder.startWith(event1, event1.getTimestamp());
    DataStream<DoorEvent> stream = createTestStream(builder).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TestTimestampExtractor<DoorEvent>());

    // Act
    Pattern<DoorEvent, ?> pattern = StatusNotFollowedByAnotherStatusPattern.getPatternForSameDoor(1, "firstevent", "statusaaaaaa","secondevent", "status2");
    PatternStream<DoorEvent> pStream = CEP.pattern(stream, pattern);

    DataStream<Either<Integer,Tuple2<Integer,Integer>>> patterns = pStream.select(getEventIdOfTimeoutEvent(),selectEventIdsOfPatterns()).forward();
    patterns.print(); //  prints Left(123)

    ExpectedRecords<Either<Integer,Tuple2<Integer,Integer>>> expectedRecords = 
        new ExpectedRecords<Either<Integer,Tuple2<Integer,Integer>>>()
            .expect(new Left<Integer, Tuple2<Integer,Integer>>(123));

    expectedRecords.refine().sameFrequency();

    // Assert
    assertStream(patterns, expectedRecords); 
}

private PatternSelectFunction<DoorEvent, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> selectEventIdsOfPatterns(){
    return new PatternSelectFunction<DoorEvent, Tuple2<Integer,Integer>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3830508947015151715L;
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer,Integer> select(Map<String, List<DoorEvent>> pattern) throws Exception {
            Tuple2<Integer,Integer> t = new Tuple2<Integer,Integer>();
            t.f0 = pattern.get("firstevent").get(0).getId();
            t.f1 = pattern.get("secondevent").get(0).getId();
            return t;
        }
    };
}

private PatternTimeoutFunction<DoorEvent, Integer> getEventIdOfTimeoutEvent(){
    return new PatternTimeoutFunction<DoorEvent, Integer>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Integer timeout(Map<String, List<DoorEvent>> arg0, long arg1) throws Exception {
            int id = arg0.get("firstevent").get(0).getId();
            System.out.println("Timeout triggered on eventstatus " + arg0.get("firstevent").get(0).getDoor().getStatus());
            return id;
        }

    };
}
```

My code does print the `status statusaaaaaa`, which is the status of my first event that is in the pattern, in the `patternTimeoutFunction`. the second status is not detected within the defined timeperiod so the timeout gets called and adds an integer to the patterns stream. How do I say in my ExpectedRecords that I expect an Either Left with a value of 123?

**EDIT**
The error I currently have is:

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:933)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:876)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:876)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred while processing valve output watermark: 
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor$ForwardingValveOutputHandler.handleWatermark(StreamInputProcessor.java:289)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamstatus.StatusWatermarkValve.findAndOutputNewMinWatermarkAcrossAlignedChannels(StatusWatermarkValve.java:173)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamstatus.StatusWatermarkValve.inputWatermark(StatusWatermarkValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:188)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:263)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:702)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:530)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:503)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:891)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:869)
    at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.TimeoutKeyedCEPPatternOperator.emitTimedOutSequences(TimeoutKeyedCEPPatternOperator.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.TimeoutKeyedCEPPatternOperator.advanceTime(TimeoutKeyedCEPPatternOperator.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.AbstractKeyedCEPPatternOperator.onEventTime(AbstractKeyedCEPPatternOperator.java:242)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.HeapInternalTimerService.advanceWatermark(HeapInternalTimerService.java:275)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.InternalTimeServiceManager.advanceWatermark(InternalTimeServiceManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.processWatermark(AbstractStreamOperator.java:946)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor$ForwardingValveOutputHandler.handleWatermark(StreamInputProcessor.java:286)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:530)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:503)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:575)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:536)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:891)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:869)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:528)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: Type extraction is not possible on Either type as it does not contain information about the 'left' type.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.EitherTypeInfoFactory.createTypeInfo(EitherTypeInfoFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.createTypeInfoFromFactory(TypeExtractor.java:1233)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateGetForObject(TypeExtractor.java:2054)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getForObject(TypeExtractor.java:2044)
    at io.flinkspector.datastream.functions.TestSink.invoke(TestSink.java:82)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:528)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a bug in spectors `TestSink` function. The `TestSink` function tries to extract the generic parameter of `Left` at runtime which is not possible. Instead it would be necessary to pass this information into the `TestSink` function when it is instantiated in order to create the correct type serializer. Please open a corresponding issue at the Github repository to let the developers know.

Comment: made an issue on their github. Thx for the reply:)